# Strapi project showing URL is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

i am trying to setup strapi application and run the application

i followed this doctument

> https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/getting-started/installation.html#requirements
>   https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/getting-started/quick-start.html#_1-create-a-project

i am successfully setup the steapi and successsfully created the application. but when i am trying to start the application using `strapi start`, it's showing below error.

[image]

Comment: Can you try using node 10?

Comment: In my case if was due to the node version. I had version 8. I've updated to node 10 and now it works great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update **C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strapi\lib\core\configurations.js** file with below

```
this.config.admin.url = this.config.admin.devMode ? `http://${this.config.host}:4000/admin`:`http://${this.config.host}:1337/admin`;
```

update project directory **config\hook.json** file with below

```
"timeout" : 7000
```

Comment: This solution works. Also works to update node version to 10